# When the login button is clicked, the url is changed, but it does not go to the login page

Tags: reactjs

```
//App.tsx

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Router />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//Router.tsx

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/signup">
            <SignUp />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

This image is Login Page
[image]

When I clicked the Login Link in `App.tsx`,
[image: Login Page]

URL was changed to `/login`, but I have to refresh for it to take effect. just see empty page..

I want to show the login page right away when I click the login link.

Answer (score 1):

React router is not recognizing the state change because it only takes place in the child component (`Router.tsx`).

Move all the JSX from `Router.tsx` into the main `App.tsx` file. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From react-router docs You should never have more then one **BrowserRouter** component you used this multiple times this whats cause your error.

Your App component required to warped inside   **BrowserRouter** at App.tsx file only ones.

```
//App.tsx

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Router />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

change your Router.tsx file by flowing way

```
//Router.tsx
    const Router = () => {
      return (
          <div className="App">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/login">
                <Login />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/signup">
                <SignUp />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Router;
```